# Copy and paste the selected text to the clipboard using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm building a custom right-click menu for my system and I need to know how can I make a JavaScript function to copy the selected text, basically 100% like the original right-click menu does.

I'm aware of the Flash work-arounds. I want to do this in JavaScript.

Every answer I've seen so far is only a half-answer because none of them explains how to make a copy button for the selected text - all what they do is copy a pre-defined text or a text from a textbox.

Comment: That's exactly the issue--there isn't a cross-browser method to do this.

Comment: yes, but you can use little flash part to do that.. just google for it (examle http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/javascript-copy-to-clipboard.html)..

Answer (score 1):

Modern Day Browsers block access to the clipboard. The user has to have the security setting correct.

There are flash [work-arounds](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/), but they are not the best.

Answer (score 0):

no idea if this will work, but a google search yielded:

```
function getSel(){
  var w=window,d=document,gS='getSelection';
  return (''+(w[gS]?w[gS]():d[gS]?d[gS]):d.selection.createRange().text)).replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
}
```

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2914

Answer (score 0):

A workable cross-browser approach (minus iOS) would be to use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) and [setClipboard](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001576.html).
So you would have a swf, flash file, that only listens to a function you call from Javascript to set the clipBoard.

Answer (score 0):

For non-IE browsers you will most likely have to use a flash solution. For IE, however, this method works perfectly:

```
function copyToClipboard(s) {           //only works in IE :(
    if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
        clipboardData.setData('text', s);
    }
}
```

Comment: well the thing is - i need it to copy exactly the text they selected, so all the answers i got here so far are only half-answers because i need my users to chose what text they want to copy and not what the current script does (copy a text that I write). It's not hard to go into Goggle and find the exact same thing as you gave below, thanks for the answer anyway ;)